# Wordpress - no global $wp_query in template file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm working within a child theme on a WooCommerce template page called `archive-product.php`, and `var_dump($wp_query)` and it returns `NULL`.

**Question:** Is this behavior typical?

(From my experience it should already be initialized by this point.)

Comment: Could you please post some code what you have tried ?

Comment: @ManthanDave thats just it, the `archive-product.php` template is completely blank I just created it to override the default, but typically the `$wp_query` is loaded before template files, is it not?

Comment: if you want to load anything you need to define - global $post; at the top of the file and then you can use $wp_query

Comment: @ManthanDave okay so your saying only the `index.php` gets the `$wp_query` initialized by default and only way for the templates to get it is if you declare it to pull it in, correct?

Comment: yes its correct but you can use $wp_query in any template but you need to define - global $post

Comment: @ManthanDave got it makes sense now. The other question I had in relation to this is modifying the main query with `pre_get_posts`. So say I add a `pre_get_posts` (and pass lets just say a category arguments which will query products by category) in the `functions.php` and then declare `global $posts` in the template file and start the loop the main query should be modified?

Comment: - Yes dats correct you can modified it by using same . you need to write your query using wp_query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125872/discussion-between-jordan-davis-and-manthan-dave).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load anything you need to define - **global $post;** at the top of the file and then you can use **$wp_query**

Try below code :

```
add_action('init','your_func');function my_func(){
    global $wp_query;
    var_dump($wp_query);
    // or  var_dump($GLOBALS['wp_query']);
}
```

Comment: so I defined `global $post` and `var_dump($wp_query)` and still returning `NULL`

Comment: I added `global $post` and that `add_action` and function returns blank. This is supposed to be in the template file right?

Comment: Isn't the query already ran by this point it gets to the templates?